# 404 Error When Accessing a File in a Private Repo with a PAT on GitHub

Tags: git

I'm encountering an issue while trying to access a file in a private GitHub repository from my application. I have generated a Personal Access Token (PAT) and am using it in the request header as Authorization: Bearer {PAT_TOKEN}, but I keep receiving a 404 error.

The file I'm trying to access is part of a private repository's release assets. I can confirm that the link works correctly when accessed directly through my GitHub account: `https://github.com/AndonMitev/tauri-updater-private-repo/releases/latest/download/latest.json`. This URL allows me to download the file without any issues when I'm accessing from the browser. Also have similar url but in public repo for testing purposes

However, when I attempt to fetch this file using the PAT in my application, it fails. Here's a brief overview of what I've done:

Generated a PAT with full repository access to eliminate any permission-related issues.
Used the PAT in the request header in the format: Authorization: Bearer {PAT_TOKEN}.
Despite these steps, I'm still facing a 404 error. Any insights or suggestions on what might be going wrong or what I should check would be greatly appreciated.